# How to multiply tensors with different shapes/dimensions?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, matrix-multiplication, array-broadcasting

I have a convolutional autoencoder model. While an autoencoder typically focuses on reconstructing the input without using any label information, I want to use the class label to perform class conditional scaling/shifting after convolutions. I am curious if utilizing the label in this way might help produce better reconstructions.

```
num_filters = 32
input_img = layers.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1)) # input image
label = layers.Input(shape=(10,)) # label

# separate scale value for each of the filter dimensions
scale = layers.Dense(num_filters, activation=None)(label) 
# conv_0 produces something of shape (None,14,14,32)
conv_0 = layers.Conv2D(num_filters, (3, 3), strides=2, activation=None, padding='same')(input_img) 

# TODO: Need help here. Multiply conv_0 by scale along each of the filter dimensions. 
# This still outputs something of shape (None,14,14,32)
# Essentially each 14x14x1 has it's own scalar multiplier
```

In the example above, the output of the convolutional layer is (14,14,32) and the scale layer is of shape (32,). I want the convolutional output to be multiplied by the corresponding scale value along each filter dimension. For example, if these were numpy arrays I could do something like `conv_0[:, :, i] * scale[i]` for i in range(32).

I looked at `tf.keras.layers.Multiply` which can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Multiply), but based on the documentation I believe that takes in tensors of the same size as input. How do I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to loop. Simply do the following by making two tensors broadcast-compatible,

```
out = layers.Multiply()([conv_0, tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(scale,axis=1), axis=1)])
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about that. Is that `None` necessary (my understanding is that it's implicitly there but I could be totally wrong)?

Comment: @JaneSully actually I updated my answer, this might be safer.

Comment: @JaneSully also it would work even without `tf.expand_dims` because tf is smart enough to infer the correct dimensions that matches and multiply. But I like to match dimensions as that's a safer option

Comment: Awesome, I just noticed that it inferred correctly for my toy example but wasn't sure if this  would always be the case. I agree matching dimensions seems safer.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i actually understood what you are trying to achieve but i did a quick numpy test. I believe it should hold in tensorflow also:

```
conv_0 = np.ones([14, 14, 32])
scale = np.array([ i + 1 for i in range(32)])
result = conv_0 * scale
```

check whether channel-wise slices actually scaled element-wise in this case by the element found at index 1 in scale, which is 2

```
conv_0_slice_1 = conv_0[:, :, 1]
result_slice_1 = result[:, :, 1]
```

Comment: I edited my question to hopefully provide more clarity. Essentially I'm unsure of how to deal with multiplying tensors with different shapes. I agree in numpy this makes total sense.